# mysql PHP join - syntax issue

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to join 3 tables but I keep getting an error with my query. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I must be doing something incorrect with my syntax but I am not quite sure what is wrong.

```
SELECT project_timecard_tasks.DateTime,
        project_timecard_tasks.Total_Hours,
        project_timecard_tasks.User_ID,
        project_timecard_tasks.Task_ID,
        project_timecard_tasks.Project_ID,
        users.User_ID,
        users.FirstName,
        users.LastName,
        tasks.id,
        tasks.taskName

 FROM project_timecard_tasks

 JOIN project_timecard_tasks ON project_timecard_tasks.User_ID = users.User_ID 
 AND project_timecard_tasks.Task_ID = tasks.id

 WHERE project_timecard_tasks.Project_ID = '$jobNumber'
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: From what I can see you need to JOIN on users table and tasks table

Comment: Error in query [query here] LIMIT 0,100

Comment: there's no limit in the query posted.

Comment: sorry...full error:Error in query SELECT project_timecard_tasks.DateTime, project_timecard_tasks.Total_Hours, project_timecard_tasks.User_ID, project_timecard_tasks.Task_ID, project_timecard_tasks.Project_ID, users.User_ID, users.FirstName, users.LastName, tasks.id, tasks.taskName FROM project_timecard_tasks JOIN project_timecard_tasks ON project_timecard_tasks.User_ID = users.User_ID AND project_timecard_tasks.Task_ID = tasks.id WHERE (project_timecard_tasks.Project_ID = '6') LIMIT 0,100

Comment: @dagon can you explain further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `JOIN` statement is a little wonky.  Try this:

```
SELECT project_timecard_tasks.DateTime,
        project_timecard_tasks.Total_Hours,
        project_timecard_tasks.User_ID,
        project_timecard_tasks.Task_ID,
        project_timecard_tasks.Project_ID,
        users.User_ID,
        users.FirstName,
        users.LastName,
        tasks.id,
        tasks.taskName

 FROM project_timecard_tasks

 JOIN users ON project_timecard_tasks.User_ID = users.User_ID 
 JOIN tasks ON project_timecard_tasks.Task_ID = tasks.id

 WHERE project_timecard_tasks.Project_ID = '$jobNumber'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting data from three tables `(project_timecard_tasks , users and tasks)` but in `from` clause you are mentioning only 1 table. you need to mention all tables names like:

```
 FROM project_timecard_tasks ,users, tasks
```

Comment: but the error you have posted in above comment. there is no limit in your query then how you are getting that error ?

Answer (score 0):

You JOIN is incorrect.  You need to specify the tables you are joining.  Replace it with:

```
JOIN users ON project_timecard_tasks.User_ID = users.User_ID 
JOIN tasks ON project_timecard_tasks.Task_ID = tasks.id
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `AND` and use `JOIN` in the second join statement.

`JOIN project_timecard_tasks ON project_timecard_tasks.User_ID = users.User_ID 
 JOIN project_timecard_tasks.Task_ID = tasks.id`